# How to bind EF Code First DbContext to an Asp.Net DataSource?

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework, datasource, objectcontext

I've created the following `Context` to be used with **Entity Framework *Code First***:

```
public class Context : DbContext
    {
        public DbSet<Animal> Animals { get; set; }
    }
```

Now I would like to use this `Context` in an Asp.Net application to perform **CRUD** operations using a `GridView`. I need to create a `DataSource` to do the data binding. How would I go about?

The ASP part would look like this:

```
<asp:GridView runat="server" DataSourceID="animalDataSource" DataKeyNames="AnimalID" AutoGenerateColumns="false">   
    <Columns>
        <asp:BoundField DataField="Description" HeaderText="Description" />
        <asp:CommandField ShowCancelButton="true" ShowEditButton="true" ShowDeleteButton="true" />
    </Columns>
</asp:GridView>
```

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6341383/how-to-create-a-nested-gridview-to-edit-ef-code-first-relation-of-ienumerablet

Comment: Great Q&A thanks, I retaged: -crud +objectcontext in order to try help searching. Because I didn't find this by searching for `DBContext ObjectContext GridView`. the retagging didn't help tho :-\

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can use `EntityDataSource` as source for your `GridView` and implement handler for `ContextCreating` event:

```
protected void DataSource_ContextCreating(object sender, EntityDataSourceContextCreatingEventArgs e)
{
    var context = new Context();
    e.Context = ((IObjectContextAdapter)context).ObjectContext;
}
```

Then you just need to configure the data source in the page. `EntitySetName` should be hopefully same as your `DbSet` property name exposed on the context.

Other way is using `ObjectDataSource` which will make a bridge between `GridView` and `DbSet<Animal>` but this can be more complex especially if you want bi-didrectional data binding.

Comment: Nice, it does the job. The only problem is that the update will throw the exception: "Update is disabled for this control."

Comment: Hahaha... but that was easy to fix. Thanks for the answer man!!

Comment: Add this to your EntityDataSource in your aspx:  EnableInsert="True" EnableUpdate="True"