# Convert DBContext to ObjectContext for use with GridView

Tags: gridview, entity-framework-4.1, ef-code-first, entitydatasource

I have a webforms project using EF codefirst to persist data.
I'd like to use a GridView and EntityDataSource, in order to save writing CRUD. 
Is this possible?

Can I convert my DBContext to an ObjectContext that is expected by the EntityDataSource?

Here's what I tried:

```
<asp:EntityDataSource ID="OrdersDataSource" runat="server" ContextTypeName="SomeNamespace.Models.ShopDBContext" 
     EnableFlattening="False" EntitySetName="Orders" EntityTypeFilter="Order" EnableDelete="False" 
     EnableUpdate="False" Include="OrderLines" OrderBy="it.Id"> 
</asp:EntityDataSource>

<asp:GridView ID="OrdersGridView" runat="server" AllowPaging="True" AllowSorting="True" 
     AutoGenerateColumns="True" DataKeyNames="Id" DataSourceID="OrdersDataSource" />
```

However I get this exception:

> Unable to cast object of type 'SomeNamespace.Models.ShopDBContext' to type 'System.Data.Objects.ObjectContext'.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to bind EF Code First DbContext to an Asp.Net DataSource?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6327937/how-to-bind-ef-code-first-dbcontext-to-an-asp-net-datasource)

Comment: Indeed it is a duplicate, thanks (note: a search for "DBContext ObjectContext GridView" will find this but not the question with an answer)

Answer (score 74, accepted):

Try this:

```
var context = new YourDbContext();
var adapter = (IObjectContextAdapter)context;
var objectContext = adapter.ObjectContext;
```

Comment: god been looking all over the place for those lines. Thanks!

Comment: This might be a dumb question but if 'YourDbContext' inherits 'IObjectContextAdapter', why do you have to cast it? Shouldn't 'YourDbContext' instantiate ObjectContext?

Comment: Because the IObjectContextAdapter interface has only one property (ObjectContext) which is implemented on a private way on the DbContext Class.
Check this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/792908/what-is-a-private-interface

Answer (score 4):

Try this one ->

```
protected void OrdersDataSource_ContextCreating(object sender, EntityDataSourceContextCreatingEventArgs e)  
{   
    var context = new YourContext();
    e.Context = ((IObjectContextAdapter)context).ObjectContext;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

After 2 days of struggling , I found this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13282083/contextcreating-method-in-entitydatasource-cannot-convert-entities-to-objectcont) which helped me a lot.I am working withVS 2012 and I had same problem with DBContext. 
According to the link, in VS2012 the default code generator was changed to generate POCO entities and DBContext as opposed to entities derived from EntityObject and ObjectContext which was default in VS2010. 
In solution explorer, under your entity model,  You need to remove tt templates and, in the designer, righ-click on the designer surface and then in the properties change the code generation strategy from None to Default to get EntityObject based entities and ObjectContext derived context.