# Get a reference to ObjectContext EF code first

Tags: entity-framework, ef-code-first

I need to load the navigation property of an entity. I've been reading a [great article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/hh205756.aspx) on different approaches how to load navigation properties with Entity Framework (6.0).

> The second way to explicitly Load is from the ObjectContext, rather
>   than from EntityCollection or EntityReference. If you’re relying on
>   POCO support in the Entity Framework, your navigation properties won’t
>   be EntityCollections or EntityReferences, and therefore won’t have the
>   Load method. Instead, you can use the ObjectContext.LoadProperty
>   method. LoadProperty uses generics to identify the type that you’re
>   loading from and then a lambda expression to specify which navigation
>   property to load. Here’s an example of using LoadProperty to retrieve
>   the Pets for a particular person instance:
>
> ```
> context.LoadProperty<Family>(familyInstance, f => f.Pets)
> ```

Now the only thing I need to know:

*How do I get a reference to the ObjectContext?*

`DbContext` does not seem to derive from it, nor does it hold a reference to it. The `LoadProperty<T>` is not static, so I do need an object reference.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Convert DBContext to ObjectContext for use with GridView](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8059900/convert-dbcontext-to-objectcontext-for-use-with-gridview)

Comment: Yo thx a lot. Will delete the question. Sorry for the duplication.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are 2 ways that I know of to load related collections with a DbContext.

One is the option you have asked about, but there is another way that I have been using for some time now and does not require a reference to ObjectContext. This method works from the DbEntityEntry collection. Here's an example:

```
public void Load<TEntity, TElement>(
        TEntity entity, 
        Expression<Func<TEntity, ICollection<TElement>>> relation)
    where TEntity : AbstractEntity, new()
    where TElement : AbstractEntity, new()
{
    var x = _context.Entry(entity);
    if (!x.State.Is(EntityState.Detached) && !x.State.Is(EntityState.Added))
        x.Collection(relation).Load();
}
```

or

```
public void Load<TEntity, TElement>(
        TEntity entity, 
        Expression<Func<TEntity, TElement>> relation)
    where TEntity : AbstractEntity, new()
    where TElement : AbstractEntity, new()
{
    var x = _context.Entry(entity);
    if (!x.State.Is(EntityState.Detached) && !x.State.Is(EntityState.Added))
        x.Reference(relation).Load();
}
```

Comment: Hmmmmm that is a nice alternative indeed. I could upvote and accept your question, the problem is that you 666 points! That's a damn shame isn't it ;-). Will un-satan you anyway. thx for the answer :)

Comment: @bas yes it is a shame, but it couldn't last ;-)