# Trying to generate an ObjectContext with Entity Framework 6

Tags: vb.net, entity-framework

I am doing some experimentation at present, familiarising myself with vs2013 and the new ef6.  I am also trying to use EF6 with componentone's datasource which requires an Object context to work with.  In VS2012 with EF5 I was able to achieve what I required by removing the .TT files and setting the Code generation Strategy to Default.

This does not work with EF6  and vs2013, but I have found a tool from the visual studio Gallery which is supposed to allow one to generate an object context.
[EF 6.x Entity Object Generator](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/ff479d55-2c85-43c5-a4d6-21cd659435ea)

I have downloaded this and , as far as I can tell followed all instructions but it still does not offer me the option to invoke a Legacy ObjectContext.

Has anyone been able to successfully use this tool and if so could they point out how they managed to get it to work.  Clearly I'm missing something but I'm not sure what.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Convert DBContext to ObjectContext for use with GridView](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8059900/convert-dbcontext-to-objectcontext-for-use-with-gridview)

Comment: ObjectContext has been moved from `System.Data.Objects` to `System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects`