# How to return a generic entity using EF6 datacontext?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-6

I have a simple database with a '`Person`' and a '`Subscription`' table where each person has one or more subscriptions.

```
    private MyDBContext_dbContext;       

    public T GetByID(int ID)
    {
        return _dbContext.Mapping. ??
    }
```

Now the intention was to create a generic method to return either a Person entity or a Subscription entity from the datacontext based on the type provided.

In Linq2SQL I was able to use `.GetTable<T>` method, how can I do the same here with EntityFramework 6? The `.Mapping` part isn't even recognized by intellisense, so i am missing something basic here.

Thanks

Comment: I'm not sure if this will help, but EF's DatabaseContext is different than previous ObjectContext's, however you can access the object context like so and perhaps find familiar ground: http://stackoverflow.com/a/8084807/84206

Comment: http://www.itworld.com/development/409087/generic-repository-net-entity-framework-6-async-operations This article discusses Generic Repository Pattern.  Please consider pros and cons very carefully. If you application is big and has a long life-cycle with many updates and changes down the road, a generic repo may not be a good idea.

Comment: +1 @rommik Oh this article is great - thanks , why might it not be a great idea btw?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

DbContext offers you Set method. You may either use it as generic method:

```
DbSet<Person> people = DbContext.Set<Person>();
```

or non-generic:

```
DbSet<Person> people = DbContext.Set(typeof(Person)) as DbSet<Person>;
```

Comment: But I need to specify DbContext.Set(T) so it just examines Type of T and returns the right entity from datacontext ? :(

Comment: But isn't that what GetTable<T> method does? What is the difference that you're looking for? To find entities by id after calling Set<T> method you may call Find method.

Comment: If you want to find the entity on given table by id just use: context.Set<T>().Find(id)